# Days don't stay expanded when switching sort orders

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, reputation-history

When clicking on the Reputation tab on your user profile it auto expands the first couple of days.

If I expand another day and then switch between sort orders, the day that I expanded becomes collapsed.

Is this a bug or by-design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed by-design, it's assumed if you're looking for a different view, you're looking for something....well, different.

As another example, if you go to page 2 and change the view, you'll also go to page 1 of the view you're moving to...this is consistent with all tab behavior across the site.